# Dividing given rectangle into regions with certain finite points being given

Tags: convex-analysis

The problem I am facing is as follows. Suppose we have a unit square and we have been given certain no. of finite points, n (For eg n=5) which are randomly spread in the square. Now, we want to partition the square into n convex parts (n=5 here) using these points. So, how can we proceed further? I am stuck at this point - any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Using these points refer to "voronoi diagram". What I am seeking here is an algorithm that could be implemented in matlab to find such regions.

Comment: This is rather vague---what exactly does "using these points" mean? Do you mean, e.g., using a Voronoi diagram? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: What do you mean with "using" the points?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? That might help us get some idea what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you just want an implementation, Matlab already includes a "voronoi" function that computes the regions (and optionally plots them). The code is commented if you want to understand what it's doing.